# Matlab - using a function mulitple times in the same workspace, to add values and fields to a structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a structure such as:

```
specimen.trial1 = 1
```

I now want to add another trial to the specimen, so that

```
specimen.trial1 = 1

specimen.trial2 = 2
```

I can do this without a problem within the workspace and command window. But, if I'm using a function to calculate the numbers for each trial (with dynamic fields), the new field and value erases the previous one. Eg:

```
function [specimen] = dummy(trial,value)
      specimen.(trial) = value
end
```

run the function:

```
[specimen] = dummy('trial1',1)
```

then run the function again with different inputs, but keeping the structure intact in the workspace

```
[specimen] = dummy('trial2',2)
```

Instead of getting a structure with 2 fields, I get just one with Trial2 being the only field. Does that make any sense? What would like is to use the outputs of a function to progressively add to a structure.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: You cannot append to `specimen` in the calling workspace in such a manner. You need to pass the `specimen` to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it makes sense, because you're creating a new struct `specimen` within your function.

**Solution:** pass the the previous specimen to the function as well.

```
function [specimen] = dummy(specimen,trial,value)
      specimen.(trial) = value
end
```

and call:

```
[specimen] = dummy(specimen,'trial1',1)
```

**or alternativly** leave out the assignment at all and use the following

```
function [output] = dummy(value)
      output = value
end
```

and call:

```
[specimen.trail1] = dummy(1)
```

which really depends on what you actually want to do. Put passing a name to a function which uses this name to define a struct is a little pointless unless you "use" that name otherwise. Also if you want to have input-dependent dynamic names you'd also go with the first alternative

Comment: +1. Note that you can also declare 'specimen global' at the beginning of the main script and of the function. This is not always recommended, but it works and sometimes is necessary.